# Google Colaboratory not displaying link during authorisation

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I created a new Colaboratory notebook and wanted to simply authenticate myself to have access to files on my Drive. However when I'm running script below

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse --headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

The only thing I can see is the text input, without any link, nothing.

[image]

When I type just anything then I receive `/bin/sh: 1: google-drive-ocamlfuse: not found`. This happens to me quite often recently, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check if this [github post](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/issues/114) resolves your issue? And also from the said github post, you will find the post about [Memory leak when continuous usage](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/issues/215), can you give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Since originally answering this question, Google has added built-in Drive FUSE support. You can mount your Drive files using the more compact snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

A complete example of installing and mounting your Drive files using this utility is available here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q